# Vim key maps act weird in urxvt

Tags: vim, terminal, zsh, xterm, rxvt

Recently I started to use & favor `urxvt` due to its vast amount of options and because of the transparency feature.

Unfortunately, some key mapping in `Vim` do not work in `urxvt`.

For example, I have mapped `Ctrl + Up/Down` and `Shift + Up/Down` to 5 respectively 10 lines up/down movement or `Ctrl + Left/Right` to 1 word left/right movement.

These movement commands do work without any problems in `xterm`, but they refuse to work in `urxvt`: they switch to insert mode and paste `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` as input into my vim.

Why does this happen?

I also use `zsh` as my shell and mapped `Ctrl + Left/Right` to move 1 word left/right in `zsh`: this also stopped working in `urxvt` (while still working in `xterm`).

How can I get `urxvt` to correctly map the keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the description of the problem you probably overlooked the fact that key definitions in urxvt differ from xterm.  Unless you specially configure urxvt, its special keys (cursor- and keypad-keys) send different escape sequences than xterm when you modify those with shift, control, alt.

You can either use the escape sequences which urxvt sends, or you could use the [`keysym`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/urxvt) feature to configure urxvt to send comparable escape sequences.  This feature was introduced by rxvt, and extended with urxvt to allow you to specify the modifiers (shift, control, etc), which you might want to limit the `keysym` to apply on:

> keysym.*sym*: *string*
> Compile frills: Associate string with keysym sym. The intervening resource name keysym. cannot be omitted.
>
> The format of *sym* is "(modifiers-)key", where modifiers can be any combination of ISOLevel3, AppKeypad, Control, NumLock, Shift, Meta, Lock, Mod1, Mod2, Mod3, Mod4, Mod5, and the abbreviated *`I`*, *`K`*, *`C`*, *`N`*, *`S`*, *`M`*, *`A`*, *`L`*, *`1`*, *`2`*, *`3`*, *`4`*, *`5`*.

That "compile frills" is a hint that it's an optional feature.  However most packagers appear to turn on all of its options (except where they conflict).  So it's probably available to you.

There's an overview of the topic (of the escape sequences) in the ncurses FAQ *[How can I use shift- or control-modifiers?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#modified_keys)* (vim incidentally doesn't *use* ncurses or the modifier information in the terminal database—it's a *termcap* application—but that's a different problem).

Answer (score 1):

In vim, you can have:

```
set t_ku=^[OA
set t_kd=^[OB
set t_kr=^[OC
set t_kl=^[OD
```

(To get `^[OA` you press `ctrl-v` then `up` )

I use urxvt too, because it is fast, I don't use the transparency feature. In `urxvt` you may want to set option  `keysym.sym: action` read man page for more details.

#### suggestion

- If you use vim, use vim motions,  `ctrl-U/D/F/B` or `wWeEbB..`. You don't need the arrow keys at all. E.g. On my keyboard, pressing arrow keys I have to press an extra `Fn` key.. too expensive, and my fingers have to leave the homerow.
- In terminal, I suggest you getting used to `emacs-binding` to edit command line, your word jumping would be: `alt-b (back) and alt-f(forward)` There are a lot more, very common to use: `ctrl-f, c-h, c-w, a-w,c-b,c-u,c-k,a-.   etc .....` also man should not forget the `c-xc-e`